# Text decoration not working on hover while everything else does

Tags: html, css

I'm making a menu switching contents when hovering over different items.
I made CSS that displays another div relative to the one being hovered on.
I made my menu items change background colors on mouseover but I can't make them change text-decoration. What am I missing here?

I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nczoptvt/

```
<div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="topLogo" class="topLogo"><h1>Logo</h1></div>
        <div id="containerMenu" class="menuContent">
            <div id="menuItemA" class="menuItem">Menu 1</div>
            <div id="menuContent1" class="contentItem">First text</div>
            <div id="menuItemB" class="menuItem">Menu 2</div>
            <div id="menuContent2" class="contentItem">Second text</div>
            <div id="menuItemC" class="menuItem">Menu 3</div>
            <div id="menuContent3" class="contentItem">Third text</div>
            <div id="menuItemD" class="menuItem">Menu 4</div>
            <div id="menuContent4" class="contentItem">Fourth text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.topLogo
{
    height: 200px;
}

.menuContent
{
    width: 90%;
    margin:auto;
    min-width: 600px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.menuItem
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align:center;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 150px;
}

    .menuItem:hover
    {
        font: bold;
        text-decoration: navy solid underline;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

.contentItem
{
    display:none;
}

.menuItem:hover + .contentItem
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `text-decoration:` from `text-decoration: navy solid underline;` to just `text-decoration:underline`, like this:

```
.menuItem:hover{font:bold;text-decoration:underline;background-color:lightblue;}
```

[revised jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nczoptvt/1/)

Here are the only valid parameters for `text-decoration`:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration/

Answer (score 1):

`text-decoration` only takes the type of decoration, not the color or pattern.  Use `text-decoration-color` to specify the color of the underline.  Your CSS should be:

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-color: navy;
```

For Firefox you may need to add `moz-text-decoration-color: navy;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.menuItem:hover
{
    font: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your menuitem:hover class has text-decoration that works. The navy solid underline part is making your underline navy colored. If you want to change the text color, you should use

```
color:red;
```

or whatever other color you want, in your menuitem:hover class